# property type of 'System.Data.Linq.Binary' which cannot be mapped to a primitive type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, binary

I am converting MVC 3 Linq-to-Sql application to MVC 5 Entity Framework 6.1.  I am using Model First to import my tables.
To save binary images in MS SQL server:
I used the following:

```
public EmptyResult UploadVisionImage (IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> image, string desc)
        {
              var httpPostedFileBases = image as HttpPostedFileBase[] ?? image.ToArray();
        if (image == null || !httpPostedFileBases.Any())
            return new EmptyResult();
        HttpPostedFileBase file = httpPostedFileBases.First();
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
            var vi = new VisionImage();
            vi.Description = desc;
            vi.FileName = file.FileName.Split('\\').Last();
            vi.ContentType = file.ContentType;
            // Save the full size image.
            var tempImage = new byte[file.ContentLength].ToArray();

            file.InputStream.Read(tempImage, 0, file.ContentLength);
            vi.ImageData = new Binary(tempImage);
            // Create and save the thumbnail image.
            file.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            int thumbnailSize = Config.Current.ThumbnailSize;
            vi.ThumbnailImageData = new Binary(Thumbnail.CreateThumbnail(file.InputStream, thumbnailSize, thumbnailSize));
            // Commit changes.
            SelectedVisit.VisionImage.Add(vi);
            _visitRepository.Save();
            }
        return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

I get this error:

```
cannot convert system.data.linq.binary to target type byte[]
```

I checked the model in the old application both ImageData and ThunbnailImageData are Binary, however in the EF model they are byte[]; when I changed them manually to Binary, I get the above error.  Both are stored in the database as "image", I also tried varbinary, still the model shows them as byte[].
Would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: You are mixing Linq to SQL with Entity Framework. Choose one or the other, they aren't compatible with each other.

Comment: Binary only exists in L2S.

Comment: I am only using EF.  I guess will to find alternative approach.

Comment: No you AREN'T. BINARY is a type within L2S. You should use `byte[]` for your model.

Comment: I am using byte[] for the model; I did change it to Binary manually, then changed it back to byte[].  The error is in vi.ImageData = new Binary(tempImage) line.

Comment: Replace it with 'vi.ImageData = tempImage;'